# Harddrive used up in gparted, after fresh install of 13.10

Tags: installation, partitioning, 13.10, gparted

**Harddrive used up in gparted, after fresh install of 13.10**

I have just installed Ubuntu 13.10 on an old HP computer which ran on Xp. On installing Ubuntu first through memory pen and later reinstalled by disk, by computer is really slow. You can se the process of a window closing in 10 secounds before its finished.

I did top in terminal and saw that Compiz was taking all resources and I tried to mend that, but now think that the graphic card driver is a dead end[image].

I saw later that there is something wrong in the partition and disk use.  In Gparted the whole disk is used, but not in real life(se picture)

I am no able to resize the partitions and have no clue what to do.

Can anybody point me in the right direction.

the image below shows the disk situation

Comment: The questioner has jumped to conclusions. Although "How can I resize and LVM partition? (i.e: physical volume)" may answer the question asked, it won't do anything to help with the performance problem, which is likely related to Unity.

Comment: You all are right, I have made a fresh reinstall and did not thick off on LVM. Repartitioned my disk, with no apparent perfomance result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your disk, and you've presented no evidence that a disk problem is causing your sluggish performance. As laurent says, GParted doesn't give you free-space estimates on LVM.

Your speed problems are more likely being caused by Unity, which is Ubuntu's default desktop environment. Unfortunately, many newer desktop environments rely heavily on advanced GPU features, and older computers don't always have enough GPU power to keep up. Thus, you may need to switch to another desktop environment, as [discussed in this question and its answers.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available) Personally, I'd recommend LXDE or Xfce; I'd avoid Unity, GNOME 3, and KDE.

Answer (score 1):

Your partition is lvm, this is why it is marked as fully used. As far as I know, GParted doesn't work to manage lvm partitions yet.
You need to use the lvm tools (`pvs, lvs, lvdisplay, lvcreate` and so on), `parted` in terminal (not sure if it works, as I never tried) or `fdisk` to work with lvm partitions.

Answer (score 0):

You all are right, I have made a fresh reinstall and did not thick off on LVM. Repartitioned my disk, with no apparent perfomance result.

I need to dig more in to the Unity lead

Thanks guys.